# replicationStatus of Network_Storage should not be a string type

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

the document is not correct:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage

this API call:

https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/17193175.json?objectMask=mask[id,replicationStatus]

the response is:

{
    "id": 17193175,
    "replicationStatus":
    {
        "createDate": "2016-12-09T02:18:27-06:00",
        "message": "Replicant Volume Provisioning has completed.",
        "scheduleId": null,
        "typeId": 322,
        "volumeId": 17193173
    }
}

Comment: Is this a Network_Storage_Event?

Comment: Not according to the metadata and the [docs](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage). What you show looks exactly like a [Network Storage Event](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Event) which doesn't make sense. Thus, I believe you have found a bug in the API, rather than in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with the object mask, anyway you could use the workaround

```
objectMask=id;replicationStatus
```

Regards

Comment: Do you know when this can be fixed?
currently due to different defects, I need to send 3 extra requests for a endurance volume, to get lunId, replicationStatus, and storageTierLevel separately, this is really inconvenient.

Comment: Nop, sorry there is no ETA for the fix